# C# interface in IronPython

Tags: c#, interface, ironpython, genetic-algorithm, accord.net

I am trying to implement a C# interface in IronPython but am having some trouble.
I've done this before with another C# interface but have come across another one which I've not been able to resolve how to subclass in IronPython to use it successfully, here it is:

**The C# interface that I want to implement in IronPython:**

```
using System;
namespace Accord.Math.Random

{
    public interface IRandomNumberGenerator
    {
        float Mean
        {
            get;
        }
        float Variance
        {
            get;
        }
        float Next();
        void SetSeed(int seed);
    }
}
```

Here is what I have done before successfully in the past:

**C# interface to implement**

```
using System;
namespace Accord.Genetic
{
    public interface IFitnessFunction
    {
        double Evaluate(IChromosome chromosome);
    }
}
```

**IronPython implementation:**

```
class FitnessFunction(AG.IFitnessFunction):
    def Evaluate(self, chromosome):
        #some fitness calculation using chromosome
        return Fitness
```

Any help would be so much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out!
I figured that the interface in this instance was actually calling some other methods in the Accord.Math.Random namespace, so I went looking for which methods these were.

I also ended up using a more updated version of the IRandomNumberGenerator interface, which was IRandomNumberGenerator[T]

**Heres the C# version**

```
using System;
namespace Accord.Math.Random
{
    public interface IRandomNumberGenerator<T>
    {
        T[] Generate(int samples);
        T[] Generate(int samples, T[] result);
        T Generate();
    }
}
```

**Heres the working IronPython version**

```
class RandomNumberGenerator(AM.Random.IRandomNumberGenerator[System.Double]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.actual = AM.Random.ZigguratUniformOneGenerator()
    def Generate(self):
        return self.actual.Generate()
    def Generate(self, samples):
        return self.actual.Generate(samples)
    def Generate(self, samples, result):
        return self.actual.Generate(samples, result)
```

I've so far been able to use it for my purposes. If anyone notices any issues in the code or knows of a more proper implementation, please post!

Cheers